# use C macro in Bison semantic actions

Tags: bison

I want to create some macros for typing save which look like:

```
#define SET_LOCATION(n) \
    { @$ = @n; \
      ...}
```

But it doesn't make, the error message is `'$' is not declared in this scope`. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bison macros (`$` and `@`) are only expanding *directly* in actions -- and this expansion happens as bison generates C code.  C macros are expanded in later, when your C compiler runs on the output of bison.  So if you want to use the bison macros in a C macro, you need to ensure that they appear directly in the action, generally as an argument to the macro:

```
#define SET_LOCATION(DEST, SRC) \
       { DEST = SRC; \
         .... }
```

used as

```
SET_LOCATION(@$, @n)
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer after checking the output of Bison. When you write `@$` directly in the semantic actions, it gets replaced with `(yyloc)` by Bison. But it is **not** replaced in the case of using a C macro. Bison doesn't expand C macros. They're expanded by GCC afterwards which will certainly leads to a undeclared '$' error.